# Android invoke activity of other application in my application's process context

Tags: android

Is it possible to invoke activity of other application in my application's process context. if Yes, how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to invoke activity of other application in my application's process context.

Fortunately, that is not possible, as that would be a significant security hole.